# How do I define a build step in general for heroku

Tags: heroku, build, apt, buildpack

When using the node.js build-pack in heroku, the *postinstall* hook in package.json can be used to run a custom build script

But what if I am not using the node build-pack? For example, if I am using the [apt build-pack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt), how do I specify a custom build script? Do I still need to create a *package.json* file just to be able to have this capability?

Comment: It would help if you asked a more specific question. There are lots of buildpacks and they can be used together. What's the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Is the question not clear enough? I just want to build my code in the heroku dyno before starting it. How do I do that?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you want the build script to do. For example, it's possible to use multiple buildpacks with a single app. If your script is supposed to, say, install a bunch of Ruby gems and then build a Rails application, we may be able to recommend a better approach. As stated it's hard to make a good recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in that I had [two buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) on my application, one of which was nodejs. My package.json `build` script was getting run before my python dependencies had been installed, and was failing (I think the same thing would happen with `postinstall`). The solution was to reverse the buildpack order, and put the python one *before* the nodejs one, so the `build` script would have all necessary dependencies.

That same solution could apply here as well, using something like [heroku-buildpack-shell](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/niteoweb/heroku-buildpack-shell). Just put that buildpack last, and stick your build script in `.heroku/run.sh`.